# MAGENTO API SOAP V2 SalesOrder Checkout Comment

Tags: magento, soap, comments, checkout

I'am looking for a way to get the comment from the checkout using the SOAP V2.
There is no field in the salesOrderEntity and it is not stored in the salesOrderStatusHistoryEntity.

Thx a lot!

Regards, Gottfried

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different call, perhaps the salesOrderInfo instead?
Here is some sample code and part of the results

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://whatever.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'userName', 'apiKey' => 'ahardpasswordGoeshere'));
$result = $proxy->salesOrderInfo((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'orderIncrementId' => '300020318'));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but I think that our checkout-extension is storing the comment on a different place. I will have to look into the database.